# Songkick widget not displaying when pasted into HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I am trying to get the Songkick widget to work on my website but for some reason it doesn't seem to be pulling through the JS form correct and instead is just displaying the Title of the form.

Any ideas?

address is www.ekkoes.com/live

Thanks

Jon

Comment: is that the address of your site?  Is it possible for you to post some code here so we don't have to navigate to another site to help you?

Comment: Apologies - will remember this for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the " at the end of the id of center-column.

You also have to correct your widget code to

```
<a href="http://www.songkick.com/artists/7871704" class="songkick-widget" data- theme="light" data-font-color="#000000" data-background-color="#ffffff">2014 Tour Dates</a>
```